# How to create iOS apps icon with size 83.5x83.5 px

Tags: ios

I have need to create iOS apps icon with size 83.5x83.5Px, but it's not possible with Photoshop or illustrator. Is there any other way to do the same?.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create 2x of 83.5x83.5 px means 167x167 px not the 83.5x83.5 px.

Plz refer the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html). It will help you to understand about application icon.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, actually "83.5x83.5(1x,2x,3x)" this is the size in icons requirements list by client. As per you, 2x of 83.5px means 167x167 but what if 3x of 83.5px (250.5) or 1x of 83.5. again there is value with '.5'. May be I am getting confused but pls. elaborate more.

Comment: Have you refer the link that i gave you in answer according that there is no need of icon with 1x and 3x of 83.5.